# Jquery treating objects with zero width and height as invisible

Tags: jquery

When an html element has the height and width set to zero, jQuery does not find the object when using a selector and specifying visible although the object is visible.

for example

$("#test").children(":visible")

the above will ignore children of #test where the width and height is zero. Is this an intended functionality or a bug in jQuery? Is there any workaround to get the object?

Many Thanks,
Arun

PS: I'm using the latest version of jQuery - 1.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bug in jQuery (in fact, the Sizzle Selector Engine that jQuery uses). From the jQuery source

```
Sizzle.selectors.filters.visible = function(elem){
    return elem.offsetWidth > 0 || elem.offsetHeight > 0;
};
```

Just implement your own filter with different logic. The filter is declared on line 2373 in the jQuery-1.3.2.js source file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is the intended functionality. From the docs:

> How :visible is calculated was changed
>   in jQuery 1.3.2. Element assumed as
>   visible if it and its parents consumes
>   space in document. CSS visibility
>   isn't taken into account.
>   
> http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible